# How to process multiple inputs in c++ for artificial neural network

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

How does C++ process multiple inputs for an artificial neural network in real-time?

I'm assuming this is without using a spiking neural network, but a more traditional one (i.e. just a basic neural network as described here)

http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html

Is this possible in a real-time world?  I was thinking one would have to process either each input individually (which will always result in the same output, hence the dilemna), or accrue a certain # of inputs per time threshold and then process them at once...

then again, what does someone do with multiple instances of the same input?  Process it twice?

I ask this because I'm looking at neuralbot, which I believe uses a normal neural network, but I'm trying to understand ANN's first before I delve into it, and am not sure how an ANN processes multiple inputs before processing target output(s).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `in real-time` and `multiple instances`, but the way you'd code a basic NN in C++ is mainly with regular for loops over the input / applicable layer (which can be a e.g. `double[]`).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear but I'll try to answer. :)

You can see an ANN (*Artificial Neural Network*) like a particular case of Adaptive Filters.

[image: A diagram for a general AF]

There are three main elements:

1. A **sequence** of inputs x(n).
2. A *Parametric Variable Filter*. In this case the filter is the ANN and the parameters are the neurons weights.
3. An *Update Algorithm* that updates the filter parameters according to the error between desired an actual output. In ANN the most used update algorithm is the [Backpropagation Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation).

In ANN there are two steps:

- **The Training Step**. This is the hard part. You start with random neurons weights. You have a sequence of inputs and their desired outputs and you run the ANN with the update algorithm on. When the error is under a certain threshold you can say that your ANN is trained. This step is usually done *off-line* (not in real time).
- **The Execution Step**. You have the trained ANN. Now just put **in sequence** the input in it and use the output. This is usually a fast operation and can be done in real-time (if it is what you mean).

Now.. what do you mean for "multiple inputs at once"? First of all standard computers can do only a very very small number of operations at once, standard PC has 4/8 cores so can do almost 4-8 operations *at once*. This number is too low for every real world ANN applications.

You said:

> what does someone do with multiple instances of the same input? Process it twice?

The answer is *Yes*. The "Execution Step" is so fast that there are no reason to don't do it. In the "Training Step" duplicated inputs can be removed before training starts (cause the training inputs are known *a priori*). So there are no problem in this. :)